# VBA macro help needed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a project involving option chains and I need to copy the value from a single cell to another sheet in the same book every five minutes, and in the same column. However, due to my unfamiliarity with VBA this is the best macro I could make, and it's very inefficient:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Note: A1 is a placeholder, and I'm currently dealing with the information pasting, not the 5 minute timer.

How could I improve the macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lrow) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2
    
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I need it copied into a column. Example: the value for A1 on Sheet1 is 232, which is copied into A1 on Sheet2. Five minutes later, the A1 value on Sheet1 is 123, which is copied onto A2 on Sheet2.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the updated codes.